# How to fix webpack module issues in Canvas project?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, canvas, webpack

I am trying to run a canvas project in local(development) environment by referring https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Quick-Start

If I try to run `rails server` then it throws an error like `RuntimeError (you need to run webpack)`. While fixing this issue, I have referred some blogs and try to run webpack server. Again it will throws an error like `Error: Cannot find module ...`

Example:

```
module.js:487
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'yargs'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:16:13)
  at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

I am using `Ubuntu 16.04` and webpack version is `3.0.0`

How can I fix these issues? Please help me to run this canvas project.

Comment: How do you run webpack?

Comment: Its related to configuration issue. Need to reconfigure this project from the scratch by following the exact steps then this error will not occur.